# WSO2 API Manager : Swagger try it out sends OPTIONS instead of GET

Tags: wso2, swagger, wso2-api-manager

```
API Manager 4.2.0 , Windows 11 , Java 17
```

Using try it out from Swagger in a GET method ends up sending OPTIONS verb:

```
[2024-02-27 22:52:20,042] DEBUG - wire HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-23 >> "OPTIONS /service/1.0.0/api/xxx/ HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
```

Instead the produced curl output from swagger:

```
curl -X 'GET' \
  'http://localhost:8280/service/1.0.0/api/xxxx/' \
  -H 'accept: application/json' \      
  -H 'header1: 123' \
  -H 'header2: 456' \
  -H 'Internal-Key: KEY
```

And the output from swagger

```
TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.
```

Is there something else to be configured?

Comment: Could you please attach a screenshot of the browser console while the error is happening?